# Best way to render a non-cubical sandbox game?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl, voxel

In my game, the world is made of cubes, but the cubes are divided into 5 parts: a tetrahedron and 4 corners. Each type of block has two colors. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBNwD.png) is what a block might look like if one corner was cut, although each corner/face may have different colors from the rest.

The problem is, on the tetrahedral faces, I want the edges between the triangles to be seamless. So I can't use textures. (I could, but they would need to be high-res, and if I want to animate the colors (for example on water) this is not an option).

I've found these approaches:

- Drawing each triangle on each tetrahedral face, then each square on each cubical face (using a VBO and all that stuff)
  Too many polys! Lag ensues. And this was only rendering the tetrahedrals.
- Using a fragment shader on world geometry
  The math is simple: for each axis, find if the point is less than 0.5 within the cube and xor the results. This determines which color to use. I got lag, but I think my code is bad.
- 3D textures on world geometry
  This seems to be the best option given how perfectly it matches my situation, but I really don't know.
- Using instanced geometry with any of the above
  I'm not sure about this one; I've read instancing can be slow on large scales. I would need 31 meshes, or more if I want to optimize for skipping hidden surfaces (which is probably unnecessary anyways).
- Using a geometry shader
  I've read geometry shaders don't perform well on large scales.

Which of these options would be the most efficient? I think using 3d *and* 2d textures might be the best option, but if I get lag I want to be sure it's because I'm using bad code not an inefficient approach.

Edit: Here's my shader code

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 pass_Position;
in vec4 pass_Color1;
in vec4 pass_Color2;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    if ((mod(abs(pass_Position.x),1f)<=0.5f)^^(mod(abs(pass_Position.y),1f)<=0.5f)^^(mod(abs(pass_Position.z),1f)<=0.5f)) out_Color = pass_Color1;
    else out_Color = pass_Color2;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your fragment shader code?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen   Done. I'm also using a simple vertex shader to apply the projection/view matrices and pass the position and colors to the fs.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, on the tetrahedral faces, I want the edges between the triangles to be seamless. So I can't use textures. (I could, but they would need to be high-res, and if I want to animate the colors (for example on water) this is not an option).

That's not necessarily the case. Remember that OpenGL doesn't see whole objects, but just individual triangles. So when rendering that cut face, it's in no way different to just render its flat, "fleshless" counterpart.

Any hard edge on the inner tetrahedron doesn't suffer from a texture crease as the geometrical edge is much stronger. So what I'd do is to have a separate 2D planar texture space aligned with the tetrahedral surfaces, which is shared by all faces coplanar to this (on a side note: applying this you could generate the texture coordinates using a vertex shader from the vertex position).

That being said: Simple 2D flat textures will eventually hit some limitations. Since you're effectively implementing a variant of an implicit surface tesselator (with the scalar field creating the surface being binary valued) it makes sense to think about procedural volumetric texture generation in the fragment shader.

Comment: By "seamless" I mean I don't want to be able to see individual texels

Comment: @rcg238: Use GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR filtering then. If you want to avoid repetetiveness use multiple textures, each providing a different detail layer. By scaling each layer's texture coordinates using a distinct prime factor you can generate very long repetition periods. For example 3 layers scaled by the prime factors 19, 23 and 29 will repeat only after 19·23·29 = 12673 units. You can even apply slightly different prime factors for the other texture coordinates (skewing the texture).

Comment: @rcg238: Or, a completely different approach would be to use "Megatextures" (Google for it, they got popularized by Id Software in their Tech 5 Engine).